# Seperate build and push without defining containerRegistry in Devops docker build task

Tags: docker, image, build, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I am having trouble with a docker deployment to Azure Container Registry (ACR).
My goal is to build my docker image once, and deploy it over 4 environments (dev, test, acc, prd).
The reason I want to only build the docker image once is that the docker build process takes about 1 hour, which I would rather not repeat 4 times

My question is: How can I do this within azure devops without having to define the "containerRegistry" in the build task?

The problem I run into is that I have to specify a **containerRegistry** variable when building using the Docker@2 build task. Else the Docker@2 push step will fail with an error like:

```
An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***.azurecr.io/repository_name
```

I do not want to specify this value in the build process, because each environment has its own container registry. So specifying this would still require me to create a build for each individual environment.

**Build step**

```
- task:                                       Docker@2
  inputs:
    repository:                              "${{ parameters.dockerImgName }}"
    command:                                  build
    Dockerfile:                              "${{ parameters.dockerBuildDockerfile }}"
    tags: |                                  
                                              ${{ parameters.dockerImageTag }}
                                              latest
    buildContext:                            "${{ parameters.dockerBuildContext }}"
    containerRegistry:                        ${{ parameters.containerRegistry}}**
  displayName:                               "Build the image"
```

**Push step** (in another stage)

```
- task:                                       Docker@2
  inputs:
    repository:                              "${{ parameters.dockerImgName }}"
    command:                                  push
    Dockerfile:                              "${{ parameters.dockerBuildDockerfile }}"
    tags:                                    "latest"
    buildContext:                            "${{ parameters.dockerBuildContext }}" 
    containerRegistry:                        ${{ parameters.acrConnection }}
  displayName:                               "Push the image with latest tag"
```

Comment: Why do you have so many container registries? There's no reason to have more than one.  A single container registry can be shared between multiple consumers.

Comment: Basically to split up access rights for each environment. We do not want development to interfere with our production environment. So on the development environment our developers have full access to manage/build/destroy the container registry, while they can't access the production registry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as it turns out this is possible by manually retagging the docker build before pushing it, as described in the link below:

https://dev.to/n3wt0n/container-image-promotion-across-environments-build-artifact-5887

Summary:
After building the image I had to save the image as a .TAR file, after which I could publish it as an Artifact:

```
- task:                                       Docker@2
  inputs:
    command:                                 "save"
    arguments:                               "--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.dockerImgName }}.image.tar ${{ parameters.dockerImgName }}:${{ parameters.dockerImageTag }}"
    displayName:                             "Save the image as a .tar"

- task:                                       PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish:                           "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
    ArtifactName:                            "drop"
    publishLocation:                         "Container"
    displayName:                             "Publish image as an artifact"                      "Save the image as a .tar"
```

Then in a different stage I could collect the stored artifact, load the .tar file and by manually retagging it through the docker@2 step I was able to make the build accessible for pushing it.

```
    # collect the docker artifact from azure devops
- task:                                       DownloadBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName:                               "Collect docker artifact"
  inputs:
    buildType:                               "current"
    downloadType:                            "single"
    artifactName:                            "drop"
    downloadPath:                            "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)"

- task:                                       Docker@2
  inputs:
    command:                                 "load"
    arguments:                               "--input $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/drop/${{ parameters.dockerImgName }}.image.tar"

- task:                                       Docker@2
  inputs:
    command:                                 "tag"
    containerRegistry:                        ${{ parameters.acrConnection }}
    arguments:                               "${{ parameters.dockerImgName }}:${{ parameters.dockerImageTag }} ${{parameters.acrName}}.azurecr.io/${{ parameters.dockerImgName }}:${{ parameters.dockerImageTag }}"

- task:                                       Docker@2
  inputs:
    repository:                              "${{ parameters.dockerImgName }}"
    command:                                  push
    Dockerfile:                              "${{ parameters.dockerBuildDockerfile }}"
    tags:                                    "${{ parameters.dockerImageTag }}"
    buildContext:                            "${{ parameters.dockerBuildContext }}" 
    containerRegistry:                        ${{ parameters.acrConnection }}
  displayName:                               "Push the image with id tag"
```

Comment: While the link does contain an answer, we encourage you to include relevant information in your answer, since the link may eventually become stale.

Comment: Is necessary to publish the image to an artifact?. It seems optional. By the way retagging according to environments seems apropiate.